# how to change select with jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I change the select option using jquery?

Like if people click on a picture, that should change the select for "total" from 10 (current value) to $25.

I tried using

```
$("#buy").click(function () {
    $("#total").val(25);
    $("#total").focus();
});
```

But it changes the value from 10 to 25, but the text does not show for $25.

so I have the following

```
<select name = "total">
<option value = "10">$10 dollars</option>
<option value = "25">$25 dollars</option>
```

When I click on the image, the value for "total" changes from 10 to 20, but the text still shows as "$10 dollars".

Comment: `name` != `id`. Daff's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting for an id but don't have any element with that id. Change

```
$("#total").val(25);
```

to

```
$('[name="total"]').val(25);
```

And it will work just fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Daff/xkPN4/1/) is a Fiddle for it.

Comment: I tried that but still the same thing. The value of the select box changes but the text for the option still stays at $10 dollars

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select[name="total"] option[value="25"]').attr("selected", "selected")
```

Comment: What happens if another option was already selected? Now you'll have two, right? Can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: The browser probably handles it properly, but you're right.  If using this method, you'd probably want to clear all `selected` attributes beforehand.  I'd vaguely remember having problems with using `val()` on selects in old versions of jQuery. (like, 1.2)  Looks like it's working sanely now, so this method is probably only really useful for old jQuery versions.